# Disable date selection for jQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am talking about this datepicker http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html
and not about the jQuery UI Datepicker
User can navigate through months and years but not select a date.
How can I disable date selection for jQuery Datepicker ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually on the site you linked, under the Extensions tab.

```
$('#selectMonthPicker').datepick({ 
    onShow: $.datepick.monthOnly, showTrigger: '#calImg'});
```

If you want the days to be visible, but not selectable, then you'd probably need to make your own extension, based off the disableWeekends extension, also shown on the Extensions tab.